# React reusing styles (css/scss)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a .scss file in src/assets/css/button.module.css

simplified content below

```
.btn:visited{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 40px;
}
```

I want to use this style in multiple components. How can i import the css to required component

I tried importing this in another scss as below

```
@import url('../../assets/css/button.module.scss');
```

But the the styles are not getting loaded. Any advice please

Comment: just use this style in your global index css/scss file

Comment: but i think that will import this style in all the components. I want to import only in selected component

Answer (score 0):

Try using
@import '../../assets/css/button.module.scss'

If does not work try using partials